# Function definitions with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing an article in which TikZ is used for all non-inline functions. To keep the formatting consistent, I'd therefore like to use TikZ to produce function definitions like this:

[image: dodgy typesetting]

As you can see, the arrows are different lengths.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (a) at (0,0) {$\mathbf{C}(A,X)$};
            \node (b) at (3.6,0) {$\mathbf{C}(A,Y)$};
            \draw[->] (a) to node (f) [above] {$\mathbf{C}(A,f)$} (b);
            \node (c) at (0,-0.55) {$\varphi$};
            \node (d) at (3.6,-0.55) {$f \circ \varphi$};
            \draw[|->] (c) to node (g) {} (d);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

> **Question.** What can be done about this?

Comment: Why would you want to use Ti*k*Z to keep the formatting consistent? It is hardly the most obvious solution, is it?

Comment: @cfr, I'm not sure what you mean, but note that mathtools arrows look different to TikZ arrows.

Comment: You're trying to use Ti*k*Z for something better done - and more easily done consistently - without it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `array` (and some coercion).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xxxrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \xrightarrow[\quad #1 \quad]{\quad #2 \quad}%
}
\newcommand{\xxxmapstofill}{%
  {\mapstochar}
  \smash{-}\mkern-7mu
  \cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu\smash{-}\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-7mu\mathord\rightarrow
}

\newcommand{\function}[5]{%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
  #1 & \;\xxxrightarrow{#2}\; & #3 \\
  #4 & \;\xxxmapstofill\; & #5
  \end{array}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\function{\mathbf{C}(A,X)}{\mathbf{C}(A,f)}{\mathbf{C}(A,Y)}
         {\varphi}{f\circ\varphi}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The command `\xxxrightarrow` is based on `\xrightarrow`, but with some space added around the superscript or subscript, as it seems you want longer arrows (you shouldn't, in my opinion).

The cell below the arrow is filled with an arrow composed with `\mapstochar`, which is the small vertical bar which is used for making `\mapsto`. For the filling I use a modified version of `\rightarrowfill` essentially removing the dollar signs around its definition, which is find in the kernel file `fontmath.ltx`:

```
\def\rightarrowfill{$\m@th\smash-\mkern-7mu%
  \cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu\smash-\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-7mu\mathord\rightarrow$}
```

Since I'm using it in an `array` cell, it should already be in math mode. The `\cleaders` provide for the repetition segment and so for filling the space.

Comment: Excellent Prof. I am very weak with latex.+1. There is an error on your comment: The word coercion. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano *Coercion* means *strong persuasion*. I needed `\rightarrowfill` to cooperate.

Comment: How does one learn to write LaTeX at this level? Most of those commands are unfamiliar to me...

Comment: @goblin Some knowledge of the kernel and of general TeX programming at low level is necessary.

Comment: @goblin don't ever compare yourself with egreg. That is a road of pain and sorrow lying ahead of you. Trust me, I know what I'm saying...

Comment: @goblin It isn't really so difficult; I added some explanations. Of course, knowing where to find things helps.

Comment: @egreg My English is very bad. Sorry very much.

Answer (score 15):

Are you sure you want to use Ti*k*Z for that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
With TikZ:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=east] (a) at (0,0) {$\mathbf{C}(A,X)$};
            \node[anchor=west] (b) at (3,0) {$\mathbf{C}(A,Y)$};
            \draw[->] (a) to node (f) [above] {$\mathbf{C}(A,f)$} (b);
            \node[anchor=east] (c) at (0,-0.55) {$\varphi$};
            \node[anchor=west] (d) at (3,-0.55) {$f \circ \varphi$};
            \draw[|->] (c) to node (g) {} (d);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
Without TikZ:
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{C}(A,X)&\xrightarrow{~\mathbf{C}(A,f)~}\mathbf{C}(A,Y)\\
 \varphi&\xmapsto{\hphantom{~\mathbf{C}(A,f)~}}f \circ \varphi
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: If you want to keep your Ti*k*Z pictures and gradually switch to the LaTeX syntax, and if you are worried about the arrow heads, then there are good news: As @CarLaTeX pointed out, Ti*k*Z has dozens of arrow styles, some of which resemble (or coincide modulo global Ti*k*Z options) the standard LaTeX arrows. (The latter can also be changed, but this requires much more effort.) Just load the `arrows.meta` library, and redefine the arrow style e.g. by saying

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Computer Modern Rightarrow}}
```

Here is the complete code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Computer Modern Rightarrow}}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
With TikZ:
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=east] (a) at (0,0) {$\mathbf{C}(A,X)$};
            \node[anchor=west] (b) at (3,0) {$\mathbf{C}(A,Y)$};
            \draw[->] (a) to node (f) [above] {$\mathbf{C}(A,f)$} (b);
            \node[anchor=east] (c) at (0,-0.55) {$\varphi$};
            \node[anchor=west] (d) at (3,-0.55) {$f \circ \varphi$};
            \draw[|->] (c) to node (g) {} (d);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
Without TikZ:
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{C}(A,X)&\xrightarrow{~\mathbf{C}(A,f)~}\mathbf{C}(A,Y)\\
 \varphi&\xmapsto{\hphantom{~\mathbf{C}(A,f)~}}f \circ \varphi
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic, but you may also want to look at `\mathbb{C}` or `\mathbbm{C}` (which requires `\usepackage{bbm}` in the document preamble) instead of `\mathbf{C}`.

Comment: (+1) For 'Are you sure you want to use Ti*k*Z for that?' :-). Indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain how the first solution works? I don't consider the second one acceptable. Look at the arrowheads, for example; they look very different between the two solutions.

Comment: @goblin You can change the arrowheads in TikZ, there are dozens of them.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks for pointing this out! I was busy hibernating ;-)

Comment: @goblin The arrows in the second example are standard TeX arrows, which you also obtain if you use `\to`, `\longrightarrow` etc. I was proposing this solution because then the arrows look all the same.

Comment: @goblin I have added the description how you could gradually switch to the standard LaTeX way of dealing with this standard LaTeX issue. Please notice also that the vertical difference between the lines is not absolutely identical. This is because in Ti*k*Z you set it by hand whereas it is dynamically adjusted in the `align` environment. (Of course, you can modify the vertical spacing by replacing `\\` by `\\[0.03cm]`, say.)

Answer (score 3):

I, instead, I have used another way with `tikz-cd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathbf{C}(A,X) \arrow[rr, "{\mathbf{C}(A,f)}"] &  & \mathbf{C}(A,Y) \\
\varphi \arrow[rr, maps to] &  & f \circ \varphi
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Here there is another version, but I think that the length depends on the characters used. I did a lot of tests. I used the same length `[12em]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathbf{C}(A,X) \ar[r,shift left=.25ex,"{\mathbf{C}(A,f)}"]  & [12em] \mathbf{C}(A,Y)  \\
\varphi\ar[r,maps to]   & [12em] 
f \circ \varphi  \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this have the same problem though? The arrows aren't the same length...

Comment: Give me a bit of time that I make the correction.