# automated arrow length

Tags: math-mode, spacing, mathtools

I am looking for an automated way to fix arrows' length in an aligned arrangement. There are two-level approaches, such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413486/195378, where the length of the second arrow is set by using the `\phantom` method, simply inserting the upper arrow's addition.

Here's the (initial) 2-level system:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*} {2}
&{f:\ } &   \mathbb{R}  &\xrightarrow{\text{some text}} \mathbb{R}\\
&   &   x   &\xmapsto{} x^2
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

To keep the arrows at equal length, one just has to insert the `\phantom`-version of `some text` to stretch the lower one, i.e.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*} {2}
&{f:\ } &   \mathbb{R}  &\xrightarrow{\text{some text}} \mathbb{R}\\
&   &   x   &\xmapsto{\phantom{\text{some text}}}   x^2
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

But what if the second line's arrow already has (short) contents? Adding the upper line's contents makes the second one longer than the upper arrow. And let's add a third line to keep this more general:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*} {2}
&{f:\ } &   \mathbb{R}  &\xrightarrow{\text{some text}} \mathbb{R}\\
&   &   x   &\xmapsto{abc\text{some text}}  x^2\\
&   &   a   &\xhookrightarrow{} b
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

The point is: How can the lengths be equalized (automatically)?

Comment: See the eqparbox package as a starting point, it can save stuff to the aux and then use it on the next run. This can probably be combined to have it automatically get the widest. Come to think of it why even use alignat and arrows like this. This is more of a diagram, why not just use tikz-cd instead?

Comment: @daleif
tikz-cd requires additional fixing (e.g. of distances)

Comment: I know I did test it. Imo it looks better manually adjusted in tikzcd than trying to make an automatic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it easily  with the `\eqmakebox` command from `eqparbox`.It replaces the length argument of `\makebox` with tag, and all eqparboxes with the same tag have the length of the widest of them.  Based on this, I defoned n `\areqbox`  adapted to the formatting of the arguments of `\xrightarrow` (mathmode and `\scriptstyle`) (may require two compilations):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\areqbox}[2][A]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\scriptstyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*} {2}
&{f\colon} & \mathbb{R} &\xrightarrow{\areqbox{\text{some text}}} \mathbb{R}\\
& & x &\xmapsto{\areqbox{abc\text{ some text}}} x^2\\
& & a &\xhookrightarrow{\areqbox{}} b
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]